# Any way to make @periodic_task run on call only,it runs automatically on project starts?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat, djcelery

Is there any way to make `periodic_task` to run on call only, I see `Pingit()` starts as soon as i run my django-app `python manage.py runserver`

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/1"),options={"task_id":task_name})
    def Pingit():
        print('Every Minute Im Called')
```

I Would like to make it run the periodic task only if i call it by `Pingit`.

Comment: Do you mean that `Pingit()` should only be started by a manual call, but once it has been started then it will then run every 1 minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better to use a `@task` for this and get it to re-queue itself after it executes, for example:

```
@app.task
def pingit(count=0):
    if count < 60 * 24 * 7:  # 7 days in minutes
        print('Every Minute Im Called')

        # Queue a new task to run in 1 minute
        pingit.apply_async(kwargs={'count': count + 1}, countdown=60)

# Start the task manually
pingit.apply_async()
```

If you need to add positional arguments to the function, you can specify those with `args`. For example, to pass a `name` argument:

```
@app.task
def pingit(name, count=0):
    if count < 60 * 24 * 7:  # 7 days in minutes
        print('Every Minute Im Called')

        # Queue a new task to run in 1 minute
        pingit.apply_async(args=[name], kwargs={'count': count + 1}, countdown=60)

# Start the task manually
pingit.apply_async(args=['MyName'])
```

Comment: Creative approach Will, TQ!

Comment: `[2018-09-17 13:35:00,078: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task cimexapp.tasks.pingit[6530114a-4262-49fd-ad24-a22773573db0] succeeded in 0.005711002973839641s: None
[2018-09-17 13:35:00,081: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: cimexapp.tasks.pingit[9cfbe0c7-7a83-4de0-a0c0-8970330395d2]  ETA:[2018-09-17 19:05:10.073313+05:30] 
[2018-09-17 13:35:10,345: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task cimexapp.tasks.pingit[9cfbe0c7-7a83-4de0-a0c0-8970330395d2] succeeded in 0.004679549019783735s: None`  just wonder why tasks doesn't show "completed" or "successed" status ?

Comment: > How can we pass arguments to it ?

Comment: `def domainMonitorSchedule(name,count=0,):
    print(name)
    domainMonitorSchedule.apply_async(kwargs={'count': count + 1}, countdown=10)`    and calling `domainMonitorSchedule.apply_async('MyNameisXXX')`

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how you can pass a `name` argument. Hope that helps.